# Error : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3

I get this error while trying to migrate a project from Objective C to swift and use cocoa pods instead of manually added libraries and i can not trace it so i appreciate any help for solving it.

Thanks in advance..

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._ticketPaymentLabel in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._tripNumberLabel in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._ticketCountDownLabel in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._passDescriptionLabel in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._passSerialLabel in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._eventStartDateLabel in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._boardingStartDateLabel in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._ticketExpirationDateLabel in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._tripTypeLabel in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._eventPlaceNameLabel in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._tripNumberTitleLabel in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._printedMessageLabel in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._sponsor4Back in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._sponsor3Back in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._sponsor2Back in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._sponsor1Back in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._tripDestinationTime in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._tripOriginTime in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._tripDestinationName in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._tripOriginName in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._mapViewTitle in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._eventTitle in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._printedPassMessageTitle in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._eventImage in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._vendorImage in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._passVendorImage in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._qrCodeImage in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._barCodeImage in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._swipeMode in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._flipped in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController.passId in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._sponsor4 in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._tripDetailsLabel4 in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._sponsor3 in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._tripDetailsLabel3 in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._eventSeatingLabel3 in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._tripSeatingLabel3 in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._sponsor2 in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._tripDetailsLabel2 in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._eventSeatingLabel2 in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._tripSeatingLabel2 in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._sponsor1 in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._tripDetailsLabel1 in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._eventSeatingLabel1 in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_TicketViewController._tripSeatingLabel1 in:
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-99E5E166CAD49D3E.o
    /Users/ams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PassApp-ezwbfrgglhkbdwdtwkntnojcfxay/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PassApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PassApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TicketViewController-AC0A4978BB9E2178.o
ld: 93 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Try doing a clean build.

Comment: As MQLN say you must copy file twice in your project just find erase them and run projrct

Comment: I tried every thing, clean & build, clean build folder also but with no result

Comment: @RealmOfFire i do not understand, could you provide more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error means that for some reason or another, your pod is getting copied twice.

I'm assuming you've read the docs for [how to add a bridging header](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html), if you are still using libraries written in Obj-c.

If you didn't do anything wrong in your code (like accidentally copy files from a pod over manually, and then try and use a pod! I've messed this up before, it happens.) this error most often goes away by [cleaning your project and then deleting derived data.](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2015/12/how-to-delete-derived-data-and-clean.html)

Comment: Thanks, however i tried every thing, clean & build, clean build folder also but with no result.

Comment: @AhmadMahmoudSaleh did you search for ‘TicketViewController’ as well? Because it sounds like you manually copied those files into your project, and are running into problems from doing that and having the pod.

Comment: @AhmadMahmoudSaleh, Did you also delete derived data?

Comment: QMQLN Yes i manually copied some files.
I will delete the drive data and see but what about the TicketViewController ??
Thank you for your support

Comment: No problem. You can't have the files AND the pod, you have to chose one or the other! Let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks @MQLN, i deleted the derived data and checked for duplicate libraries and did not find any duplicate but still the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved after about 1.5 day, the TicketViewController.m file was added twice (duplicate) in the project Build phases >> Compile Sources, just removed one of them and the error is gone now, thank you very much @MQLN for your support